# Using jquery document.ready() on <img onload> event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I have the following need: I want to call a js each time an image is loaded on the page but
I also need that the DOM of the page is completed loaded before the js runs.

I wrote the following 'dummy' example and I would like to know if it can be considered correct or not.
It seems to work but, since jquery says: "The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the
 attribute", I would like someone to tell me: "yes, you can do that".

Thanks a lot for your help,
Nico

Example:

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mySetVal() {

       $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#status").val("Refreshing");
       });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div style="border:1px solid green">
<img src="target.jpeg" id="cat" onload="mySetVal()"></img>
</div>

<div>
<p>E poi che la sua mano a la mia puose con lieto volto, ond'io mi confortai, mi mise dentro a le segrete cose.</p>
</div>

<table>

<tr>
<th>animale</th><th>pianta</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>mucca</td><td>palma</td>
</tr>

</table>

<p>Input: <input type="text" id="status" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that, as long as jQuery is loaded before the image, since the `ready` function will be called directly if the DOM is already ready when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is exactly what $(document)ready(...) was meant for.

Look at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29

"Everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove the inline attribute onload from img tag.
You can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#cat").load(function()
    {
        $("#status").val("Refreshing");
    });
});
```